# How to alias a prototype function using es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The requirement is to have an alias to a prototype function.

Currently I'm doing this, which is adding an additional function and execution context, when called, as opposed to just a reference:

```
class X {
  x() {
    // stuff
  }

  y() {
    this.x();
  }
}
```

Because I don't know how to do this, in es5:

```
function X() {

}
X.prototype.x = function () {
  // stuff
}
X.prototype.y = X.prototype.x;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `y = this.x` (in class body)

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky assigning things this way binds them to the instance, not the prototype, but at the time this is running `this.x` would probably be undefined anyway.

Comment: Oh, right, I haven't paid enough attention to the question, sorry

Comment: I don't think that this is possible at definition time (inside the class body), but the `X.prototype.y = X.prototype.x` trick is still a valid code

Comment: @php_nub_qq Also, I'm not sure about the `undefined` thing, since `this.x` will be taken from the prototype. So, as long as you define `y` later than `x`, it shouldn't be `undefined`

Comment: @FZs you are right I broke the instance assignment and convert it to prototype. It will re-assign the prototype to the last instance every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. The easiest is doing just the same as without `class` syntax:

```
X.prototype.y = X.prototype.x;
```

If you insist on `class` syntax, [ES2022 will have static blocks](https://2ality.com/2021/09/class-static-block.html):

```
class X {
    …
    static {
        // notice unlike a method definition, this creates an enumerable property
        this.prototype.y = this.prototype.x;
    }
}
```

If you need to limit yourself to ES2015, you can still provide the `x` method as `y` in various ways:

```
class X {
    …
    constructor() {
        // notice this creates an own, enumerable property
        this.y = this.x;
    }
}
```

```
class X {
    …
    // notice this prevents assignments to `.y`
    get y() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think of myself as someone who sort of tracks TC39 proposals, but I've never heard of that "static blocks" thing before!

Comment: @FZs Yeah, they're… weird. I think they're only needed for messing with private names, and to appease java programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with classes as well, because they use the same underlying prototype-based structure.

So,

```
class X {
  x() {
    // stuff
  }
}

X.prototype.y = X.prototype.x
```

works fine.

If you want to define it in the `class`, the only way is your approach:

```
class X {
  x() {
    // stuff
  }

  y(...args) {
    return this.x(...args);
  }
}
```

However, this will still behave differently if `x` is overridden in a subclass (which might actually be what you want, if you want a *true alias*).

Comment: Yes I'm aware that I can still do it this way but I was asking if it's possible to be done in es6 syntax, so I'm guessing the answer is no?

Comment: No, the answer is no, then.

Comment: @php_nub_qq It *is* ES6 syntax

Comment: @php_nub_qq Bergi has a point in that ES6 stuff doesn't replace everything of pre-ES6-JS; and not every feature introduced ES6 is better just because of that.

Answer (score -3):

How about you add `y` in the constructor?

```js
class X {
  constructor() {
    this.y = this.x;
  }
  x() {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

Of course this will add it as an instance property; this should be no issue though because all instances simply hold a reference to the prototype method in their `y`.

If that does not meet your requirements I'm kindly asking for a clarification.

Here's how you add it to the prototype:

```js
class X {
  x() {
    console.dir(this.__proto__);
  }
}

X.prototype.y = X.prototype.x;

(new X).x();
(new X).y();
```

Comment: Why `(new X).y()` and not `new X().y()`?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky They're the same thing... it doesn't matter.

Comment: Because I'm used to omit the brackets when I instantiate an object with a parameterless constructor, and if you do that, it throws an error because it assumes `X.y()` is your constructor.